# log file generated by log4j is more than max file size

Tags: java, log4j

log file generated by log4j is more than max file size.log4j configurted in property file.here is the contents of property file.

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to R.
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, LOGFILE
log4j.logger.org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView=INFO
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File= ./logs/app.log
# Control the maximum log file size
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=1024KB
# Archive log files (one backup file here)
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=1000
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c] %m%n
what could be the reason for this?
```

Comment: I am not absolutely sure (a long time since I checked) but I think that it only checks the MaxFileSize periodically. Depending on RollingPolicy (???)

Comment: It is working on my system I test with small MaxFileSize [2KB], and there is no issue. What problem you are facing ?

Comment: What is the size it has generated, which you think its more than 1024KB ?

Comment: intially i add max size as 10MB but it created upto 106MB